# VIM range line number registers

Tags: git, vim

Is there a register or variable that holds the line numbers for currently selected range?

`line(".")` works as for the current line but is there one for in a visual range?

**EDIT**

As mentioned below the `'<` and `'>` registers hold the beginning and ending lines.

What I ended up doing in addition to using the above was writing a function in VimScript which takes those line numbers and executes an external command, I'll include it below:

```
function! Github(line1, line2)
    execute "!github -f " . expand("%") . " -l " . a:line1 . " -n " . a:line2
endfunction
com! -range Github call Github(<line1>, <line2>)
```

I'm brand new to VimScript but from what I gathered from an initial google search, the above function accepts a range.  I then take the beginning and ending line numbers and use them to execute the external script `github` which interfaces with the Github API and/or opens a browser to a github page based on the git info.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- `'<` and `'>` respectively.

  So: `line("'<")` and `line("'>")` should be what you expect
- Also,

  ```
  :'<,'>sort
  ```

  to sort the last visual selection
- <kbd>`</kbd><kbd><</kbd> to jump to the start of the last visual selection (also see `:he v_o`)
- Finally, if `'cpoptions'` does ***not*** include `*`, you can use `:*` as a synonym for `:'<,'>`:

  ```
  :se cpoptions-=*
  :*sort
  ```

Comment: Perfect answer, and even as a long-time Vim user, I learned something (`:*`, which is one key shorter than `gv:`)!

Comment: @IngoKarkat Thank you! To me, honestly, it isn't about less keystrokes; It's about a good working set to remember (small but flexible) and convenience of typing. `:'<,'>` hurts to type. I usually do `gv:` instead (so as not to depend on `cpoptions` for `:*`).